# Extract json string i.e authentication Token from Json response for next activity.

Tags: android, json, android-studio

*on postExecute()

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            if (s != null) {
                s.replaceAll("\\s+","");
                Log.e("Fetch_frame_response", s);
                userToken = s.substring(24,451);
                Log.e("userToken", userToken);
                Intent abc = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Orderlist.class);
                startActivity(abc);
                finish();
            } else {
                Intent abc = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(abc);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid credentials", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*logcat Response which is not fetching me the value i want to stored as a variable userToken

```
07-29 10:30:57.556 7341-7341/com.example.rinzinchoephel.driverdemo2 E/userToken: 2791d970-c11d-48f6-92f3-8ec4f0b14820","contactEmail":"rchomphel@gmail.com","contactPhones":"+19731488021","createdAt":"2016-07-04T01:42:11.452-05:00","description":"","email":"rchomphel@gmail.com","id":"577a051469702d0380170000","internalId":"rinzin","lastAccessedOn":"2016-07-04T01:42:11.452-05:00","name":"rinzin choephel","phone":"+19731488021","updatedAt":"2016-07-04T01:42:11.452-05:00","userType":"merchant","username":"r
```

Comment: so you want to fetch userToken? and I can see you are getting value in userToken but which also include others detail too. will you please post `String s` value.

Comment: Why are you trying to split the string and taking the value. If it is a JSON Object you can parse it using  userToken = s.getString("userToken");
Please post your String s and crash log

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            if (s != null) {
                Log.e("Fetch_frame_response", s);
                try {
                    JSONObject object=new JSONObject(s);
                    String userToken=object.getString("authenticationToken");
                    Log.e("userToken",userToken);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }  
                Intent abc = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Orderlist.class);
                startActivity(abc);
                finish();
            } else {
                Intent abc = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(abc);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid credentials", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 07-29 10:49:34.841 20164-20164/com.example.rinzinchoephel.driverdemo2 E/Fetch_frame_response: {"authenticationToken":"ac1c895d-8fe5-48c4-bb06-b65d0d57c93b","
07-29 10:49:34.841 20164-20164/com.example.rinzinchoephel.driverdemo2 E/userToken: {                     I am a beginner so is the authentication Token getting saved as variable userToken

Comment: @Rinsing I understand. So is your userToken =2791d970-c11d-48f6-92f3-8ec4f0b14820  ?

Comment: userToken is a variable i just created to stored authentication Token" " . You can c my authentication token in my previous comment

Comment: @Rinsing  Could you show the entire message shown in E/Fetch_frame_response, only then can i fetch the authentication Token?

Comment: 20164/com.example.rinzinchoephel.driverdemo2 E/Fetch_frame_response: {"authenticationToken":"ac1c895d-8fe5-48c4-bb06-b65d0d57c93b","contactEmail":"super_admin@gogreenbasket.com","contactPhones":"+18125240870","createdAt":"2016-07-28T03:58:34.589-05:00","description":"","email":"super_admin@gogreenbasket.com","id":"567cd11269702d0961010000","internalId":"Greenbasket","lastAccessedOn":"2016-07-28T03:58:34.589-05:00","name":"Greenbasket Admin","phone":"+18125240870","updatedAt":"2016-07-28T03:58:34.589-05:00","userType":"super_admin","username":"super_admin@gogreenbasket.com"}

Comment: @Rinsing Refer to these links: [link1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm) , [link2](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidJSON/article.html), [link3](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-json-parsing-tutorial)  for better understanding on how to retrieve data from JSON objects. If the above code works then upvote it & mark it as answer.

Comment: Thank u i got it . E/userToken: 55f48155-58e3-46dc-ab46-55c91035e36b

Answer (score 0):

**In you postexecute**

You must parse your json dont use substring

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        if (s != null) {

             try {
                        JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(s);
                        int status = responseObject.getInt("status");
                        String message =responseObject.getString("message");
                        if(status == 1){
                        String UserToken =   responseObject.getString("userToken");         
 Log.i("userToken",UserToken );    
 Intent abc = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Orderlist.class);
 abc.putExtra("userToken",UserToken);
            startActivity(abc);
            finish();                 
                                 Toast.makeText(context,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else if(status ==2){
                               Toast.makeText(context,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            
        } else {
            Intent abc = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(abc);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid credentials", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Note: Use SharedPrefernce to store your user data so that is can be accessed from anywhere